# Git/BitBucket Troubles With "Merge pull request" Script And Password

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

I'm using BitBucket on a project. Another person has submitted a pull request. BB usually merges for me and I pull the latest code, but this time there's a conflict I need to resolve manually. BB gives me code to input into Terminal but every time I run this code I'm prompted for a password. I'm 100% sure this isn't my BB password, and it's not my local password, so I have NO idea what password it's asking me for. I cannot complete the pull and it's driving me crazy. I've pasted the BB script below (switched real paths to placeholders);

```
git checkout master
git remote add person2/projectName https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/person2/projectName.git
git fetch person2/projectName
git merge --no-ff -m 'Merged in person2/projectName (pull request #3)' remotes/person2/projectName/master
```

Can anyone advice what the problem is?

```
git fetch person2/projectName
Password for 'https://myUserName@bitbucket.org': (I enter my BB password)
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/person2/projectName.git/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the source of the authentication error is, or if you should really be doing something which could cause that in the first place.

However, there are a few general strategies you can follow to eliminate the merge conflicts in the pull request.  I will assume that the feature branch is called `person2/projectName` and that the pull request is meant to go back into `master`.  One conceptually easy way to resolve the conflict is to first merge `master` into `person2/projectName` locally, and then push the feature branch back out to BitBucket.  Here is how you would do this:

```
git fetch origin                     # update all local tracking branches
git checkout person2/projectName     # switch to feature branch
git merge origin/master              # merge master into it
# resolve any merge conflicts...
git push origin person2/projectName  # push the branch to BitBucket
```

After resolving the merge conflicts and pushing to BitBucket, you can go to the BitBucket site and check the status of the pull request.  There should no longer be any conflicts and the pull request can now be completed.

Comment: Thanks for writing. How can I work on the person2/projectName branch if I can't download the files in the first place - am I missing something..?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know you could not fetch at all.  I assumed that you just needed help resolving the conflicted pull request.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wish I could get the merge conflict to fix it, that's the problem, I cannot get the code. I'm looking for possible reasons as to why I cannot connect to the pull request code.

Comment: Well let's debug this.  Can you login directly to the BitBucket site using that username and password?

Comment: As in, to view my repo? It's my email and password (the same as I've been putting in Terminal) and it works OK.

Comment: If you're certain that you are entering valid credentials, then the next thing to check is whether you have you certificates setup correctly.

Comment: I'll need to have a Google for this info. I assume this was done when I first started using BB with Terminal, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Google away.  I think you will likely have this resolved fairly quickly.  My answer stands for dealing with the actual merge conflict in the pull request.